# How to expand a Bootstrap 3 dropdown when viewing on desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My aim is to use a [Bootstrap 3 dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) to display links at mobile screen size and use a [list](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-lists) to display the same links when the screen is bigger (desktop and tablet size).

Dropdown markup:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

List markup:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

My thoughts were to use the [responsive utility](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) classes to display and hide the markup via media queries. For example:

```
<ul class="list-inline visible-xs-block">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

However, this approach would mean a whole bunch of links are hidden and I'm not entirely convinced hiding links in this way is a great approach. How can I achieve my aim without hiding links?

Here is a **demo** of what I'm trying to achieve:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g8c194n4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Media Queries ?*

**CSS** :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown button{
      display:none;
  }  

  #mylist {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    position: relative;
  }
  #mylist li{
    float:left;
  }
}
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/g8c194n4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Another option (if you don't need the exact style of the dropdown list) would be to use navbar-nav since it's already been designed to collapse on mobile.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myList">
    Menu <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myList">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://www.bootply.com/render/ueNgfw1cbO

**Code:** http://www.bootply.com/ueNgfw1cbO

Comment: Definitely a +1 solution, although I think in my particular case @media queries give me slightly more control over the outcome.